# What can I do to call a method after a definite interval of time repeatedly?

Tags: java, android, time, libgdx

I am using libgdx and android studio. Here I am trying to call a method(for creating a texture) after a definite interval of time, 0.5seconds.but when I am running the program it's showing "not responding" dialogue.

```
private float x=System.currentTimeMillis();

//in update method


public void update(float dt) {

        handleinput();
        while(x<=System.currentTimeMillis()){
            eggs.create();
            //eggs.update(dt);
            x+=500;
         }
}
```

What to do?

Comment: how long does your eggs.create() method takes? this method doesn't even do what you intending it to do

Comment: First of all, please use `long` instead of `float` for `x`

Comment: Thank you @quinz it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To handle time, use a variable adding delta time every time render is called, when this variable is superior a 1.0f means that one second has passed, your code would be something like this:

```
        private float timeSeconds = 0f;
        private float period = 1f;

        public void render() {
            //Execute handleEvent each 1 second
            timeSeconds +=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(timeSeconds > period){
                timeSeconds-=period;
                handleEvent();
            }

            [...]

        }

        public void handleEvent() {
             [...]
        }
```

To keep organized i personally have an array on my main game class that holds all my timed events and process everything on the render cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is literally a running competition against the clock.

The loop is probably never ending because `eggs.create()` takes more time than the increment of 500 you do for `x` in the end of the cycle.

Also using `float` instead of `long` is not good practice.

**EDIT:**
To have a proper scheduling use best known Java methods similar to what Florian S. is suggesting in his answer.

Comment: Cool that this helped. Be aware that using proper schedules would be a programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you should not be using `System.currentTimeMillis()` here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis() :

> **currentTimeMillis**
>
> Returns:the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC

```
public void update(float dt) { 
    if(dt < 500) {
        int x = 10;
        // let x be some value to increment
        update(dt + x);
    }
    ...
}
```

This version will not guarantee half a second, but will give you a better idea as to how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` or an Android equivalent for it when you want to run code cyclically. What you are doing will block the thread when egs.create() takes more than 500 ms.